# Postgres Trigger Function ON CONFLICT update another Table

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, upsert

Writing a Postgres trigger function to `INSERT` into "Copy" table upon `INSERT` in "Main" table. And on `DELETE` operation on the "Main" table, I set 'isdeleted' flag on the "Copy" table to true. However, on Insert Conflict, I wish to update the "Copy" table and the 'isdeleted' flag. Trying to use `ON CONFLICT(id) DO UPDATE` only seems to update the "Main" table and not work on "Copy" table. 'isdeleted' is not a part of "Main" table. The trigger on "Main" table is `AFTER INSERT` and `BEFORE DELETE`.

Does anyone know a work around to update another table on conflict?

```
BEGIN
  IF (TG_OP = 'INSERT')
  THEN
    INSERT INTO copy_table (id,isdeleted)
      (
        SELECT
          new.id,
          FALSE
      )
    ON CONFLICT (id)  DO NOTHING;
   */ UPDATE copy_table         --TRYING TO MAKE THIS WORK
      SET isdeleted = FALSE
      WHERE new.sfid = sfid; */
    RETURN new;

ELSEIF (TG_OP = 'DELETE')
    THEN
      UPDATE copy_table
      SET
        isdeleted = TRUE
      WHERE old.id= id;
      RETURN old;
  END IF;
END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UPDATE in ON CONFLICT section refers to the same table as the INSERT, and to the row which has been rejected. You can therefore use simple:

```
  IF (TG_OP = 'INSERT')
  THEN
    INSERT INTO copy_table (id, isdeleted)
      VALUES (new.id, FALSE)
    ON CONFLICT (id) DO 
      UPDATE SET isdeleted = FALSE;
    RETURN new;
  END IF;
```

Comment: Oh Yes. You're right. I must have messed up my testing somewhere. Thanks a ton.